# How to deploy Vue application and Node backend server application on nginx?

Tags: nginx, node.js, linode

I have vue frontend application which I have built generating index.html and dist folder containing all the bundles. In addition I have developed another express base node application which provides Restful services for the above mentioned frontend app. I have Linode ubuntu 17.10 VPS on which I have installed nginx. I do not want to use apache web server.

Can I directly copy vue application to /var/www/ so that it runs under nginx in its default configuration ?

For node backend app I intend to use PM2 which will manage/monitor running node backend app on the same Linode VPS instance running nginx. Ideally I want only vue app can invoke api to this backend node app I mean this API should not be publicly accessible and I have no clue how to achieve this.

What is the best way to deploy these two apps in the above scenario that is production grade?

Vue frontend production build is similar to react or angular app, so the answer should equally apply to these as well everything else being the same.